# Unwanted '\n' character within dictionary items (or within a list of strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any suggestions to get rid of an unwanted \n at the end of each last value of each dictionary key items?

Exemple:

```
d= {'1' : ['12', '15:23,24:26\n'], '2' : ['13', '15:6\n'],...}
```

Wanted result:

```
d= {'1' : ['12', '15:23,24:26'], '2' : ['13', '15:6'],...}
```

Or,any suggestions to get rid of them within a list of strings?

Exemple:

```
L= ['1','12','15:23,24:26\n', '2', '13', '15:16\n',...]
```

Wanted result:

```
L= ['1','12','15:23,24:26', '2', '13', '15:16',...]
```

**Edit:**

The import code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file:
    rows = (line.split('\t') for line in file)
    d_file = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows}
```

Comment: Where do the `\n` come from? How is `d` created?

Comment: The \n came from a text file, which I have imported in python as a dictionary. Would you suggest another way to get rid of it before the dictionary to be built?

Comment: Clean the data during the import. To help you with that, show us your import code.

Comment: @Dovah do you realise that `'\n'` means "new line"?

Comment: Yes, @jonrsharpe, I do.

Comment: @Dovah, it might be smarter to remove the whitespace when you're reading the file. You can call the same function there.

Comment: Anyways, @LutzHorn, there's my import code: 
`with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file:`    
`rows = ( line.split('\t') for line in file )`    
`d_file = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean your data when you first import it, rather than trying to clean it after the fact.

Here's your data-reading code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file: 
    rows = ( line.split('\t') for line in file ) 
    d_file = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
```

Add a call to `rstrip()` to remove whitespace at the end of the line:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file: 
    rows = ( line.rstrip().split('\t') for line in file ) 
    d_file = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
```

Answer (score 3):

Call [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) for each item in the list. You can use a combination of a dict and list comprehension for the dictionary:

```
In [9]: d = {'1' : ['12', '15:23,24:26\n'], '2' : ['13', '15:6\n']}

In [10]: {k: [x.strip() for x in v] for k, v in d.items()}
Out[10]: {'1': ['12', '15:23,24:26'], '2': ['13', '15:6']}
```

And just a plain list comprehension for the list one:

```
In [6]: L= ['1','12','15:23,24:26\n', '2', '13', '15:16\n']

In [7]: [x.strip() for x in L] 
Out[7]: ['1', '12', '15:23,24:26', '2', '13', '15:16']
```

The `str.strip()` -function will strip leading and trailing characters from your strings. Without parameters it will remove whitespace, which includes newlines. The list comprehensions simply call the `str.strip()`-function for each element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = {key.strip(): item.strip() for key, item in d.items()}
```

The **strip()** function removes **newlines, spaces,** and **tabs** from the **front** and **back** of a string.

[Python strip() function tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm)